# Can we use CSS in replacement of .fadeIn() in jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

The .fadeOut() method animates the opacity of the matched elements. Once the opacity reaches 0, the display style property is set to none, so the element no longer affects the layout of the page.

If above is true, then why i am facing issues to get the paragraph back?

```js
$("button").click(function() {
  if ($("#paragraph").css("display") == "none") {
    $("#paragraph").css("display") = "block";
    $("#paragraph").css("opacity") = 1;

  } else {
    $("#paragraph").fadeOut();
  }

});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<p id="paragraph">This is a paragraph</p>
<button>Click me</button>
```

Comment: What kind of "issues" are you facing?

Comment: Even after fadeOut() ,the opacity is still 1.

Comment: Use the shorthand `if ($("#paragraph").is(':hidden');` instead.

Comment: _Always_ check the documentation when something is not working -> [`.css()`](https://api.jquery.com/css). And you might also want to have a look at the [jQuery Learning Center](https://learn.jquery.com)

Comment: Will make sure of that, Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason is your are using your css assignment syntax wrong. The console would have alerted you to this. Make your changes as follows.

```html
<script
  src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.min.js"
  integrity="sha256-9/aliU8dGd2tb6OSsuzixeV4y/faTqgFtohetphbbj0="
  crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<body>
<p id="paragraph">This is a paragraph</p>
<button>Click me</button>
<script type="text/Javascript">

    $("button").click(function(){
        if ($("#paragraph").css("display") =="none"){
            $("#paragraph").css("display", "block");
            $("#paragraph").css("opacity", '1');
             
        }
        else{
            $("#paragraph").fadeOut();
        }
        
    });


</script>
</body>
```

You can ignore how i included jquery. I only did that so to ensure its all runnable here.

Comment: No. The console would not alert anything. The statements are **valid** JavaScript statement but not jQuery's

Comment: Then perhaps my browser is more *verbose*. It did in mine and was where i continued further to know. Note: on the second click of the "Click me" button in OP's original source: `Uncaught ReferenceError: Invalid left-hand side in assignment`

Comment: Writing `$("#paragraph")` four times in same code block is a bit of a code smell and requires a dom search for each call. css() also accepts an object to avoid multiple calls

Answer (score 0):

Use the shortcut method [`show()`](https://api.jquery.com/show/) instead of `css()` to make it simple

```js
$("button").click(function() {
  const $p = $("#paragraph");// cache element reference once for efficiency
  if ($p.is(':hidden')) {
    $p.show();
  } else {
    $p.fadeOut();
  }

});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<p id="paragraph">This is a paragraph</p>
<button>Click me</button>
```